# What battery should I use in a Minolta XD-11?

Tags: battery, minolta, film-cameras

I just got a XD-11 and it needs a battery.

The user guide references a **Eveready S-76** but I can't find info on the [S-76 battery model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes).

**What is the proper battery to use in a Minolta XD-11 today?**

Comment: When I typed Eveready S-76 into a search engine I found many replacements that seemed to be hearing aid button cells.  Does that seem to be the right shape for what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.35V Mercury Oxide batteries are now banned. These batteries were popular in cameras as they held a constant 1.35V while discharging which was good for accurate light meter readings in older cameras of the 1950s and 1960s.

Newer cameras like your XD-11 have “bridge circuits” that do not need a specific voltage to maintain accurate light meter readings. The user manual for the XD-11 specified S76 1.5V “Siver Oxide” batteries but these can be difficult to find.

[image]

1.5V LR44 lithium batteries are most often used as replacements because they are the same size and voltage. The Minolta XD-11 uses two of these batteries to produce 3 volts.

[image]

Here is a full list of comparable S76 replacement batteries:

G13, AG13, LR44, L1154, LR1154, 357, SR44, A76, SG13, 303, 303-1, V303, D303, SP303, V303, 357, D357, V357, GS14, SR44W, SR44SW, MS76, GP76, V76HS, WS16, 280-08, A, SB-A9, S1154, SR1154, SR47, S76E, S06, 1130SO, G13A, RPX675, D76A, V13GA, PX76A, PX675A, GPA76, 1128MP, 1166A

Another battery which some people use is a single 1/3N which is 3V and the same size as two LR44 batteries. These are also called 2L76, CR1/3N, and CR11108.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: "1.5V" batteries are always good to replace with LR44 etc., "1.35V" batteries like PX625, as used in some even older cameras with non-active electronics (eg SR-T series), are a much more complicated matter, since the calibration of these cameras relies on exact battery characteristics....